# GUI for server status

Tags: 16.04, gui

Does there any GUI available , that can shows status of server ? i.e. I have one server ip , and I want to know whether this server is up and
listening using GUI? I am using ubuntu 16.04.Regards.

Comment: you mean, only on/off or monitor the complete health of the server?

Comment: Initially , I want on/off status. It's good if I can check complete health of server.

Comment: check this https://github.com/firehol/netdata